# Import a CSV file with null values in Neo4j

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, merge, cypher

This is supposed to be a really easy task and yet I am struggling. To all the people who are expert in a graph-database and Neo4j I would really appreciate some help and make my life a bit easier. I can't seem to figure out this MERGE clause with NULL values in CSV files.

Example.csv file contains

---

```
Name,Lastname,Team,Room

AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,1111

DDDD,EEEE,FFFF,2222

GGGG,HHHH,,3333

IIII,JJJJ,KKKK,

LLLL,MMMM,CCCC,1111

NNNN,OOOO,,2222
```

---

When executing

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///EXAMPLE.csv' AS row WITH row RETURN row
```

I can see some fields like Team and Room has null values. I would like to create nodes for Employees, Team and Room and here is the code I have written so far.

---

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Team) ASSERT t.name IS UNIQUE;

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (r:Room) ASSERT r.name IS UNIQUE;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///EXAMPLE.csv' AS row WITH row WHERE row.Room <> '' AND row.Room IS NOT NULL AND row.Team <> '' AND row.Team IS NOT NULL

CREATE (m:Employee {name: toUpper(row.Lastname), firstname: toUpper(row.Name)})

MERGE (r:Room { name:row.Room})

MERGE (t.Team {name:row.Team})

CREATE (m)-[:WORKS_IN]->(r)

CREATE (m)-[:WORKS_WITH]->(t);
```

---

I guess you already guessed some entries with null values are cancelled and not taken. I want to keep the Employees within the database even it has no entries in department or team ie. no relationship exists if null.

I would really appreciate some help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/foreach/) and [CASE WHEN](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#query-syntax-case) to [handle conditions](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/06/17/neo4j-load-csv-handling-conditionals/). Something like this:

```
CREATE (m:Employee {name: toUpper(row.Lastname), firstname: toUpper(row.Name)})
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN row.Room IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END) |
    MERGE (r:Room { name:row.Room})
    CREATE (m)-[:WORKS_IN]->(r)
)
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN row.Team IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END) |
    MERGE (t:Team {name:row.Team})
    CREATE (m)-[:WORKS_WITH]->(t)
)
```

The `FOREACH` block will be executed only once when the related line is different of null.

Comment: Thank a lot Bruno!

Comment: Hi @jorzylicious You are welcome! Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I have one more question if you could help me out. After I uploaded my dataset, I noticed that some names have spaces before comma for example: AAAA ,BBBB,CCCC,1111 Here AAAA<space><comma>. So when I have to query in Cypher MATCH (n:Employee {name: 'AAAA '}) RETURN n, I have to put a space. Is there a way to avoid the space or a way to format before uploading?

Comment: @jorzylicious You can reimport your data using [trim() function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-trim) or update your nodes setting name property to `trim(node.name)`.

Comment: @jorzylicious In cases you have new questions I suggest you to Ask a New Question instead of using the comments to it. This way other users of the community dealing with the same problem can take advantage of your question and the provided answers.

Comment: It's rough that this is probably the closest thing we have to conditional statements in Cypher. It seems like a lot of queries could benefit from CASE being extended to allow conditional evaluation of inner statements